# Layer is rotating in x/y-axis instead of z-axis

Tags: ios, rotation, calayer

After creating a test project in order to help get some answers for a <strike>related question I recently asked on SO</strike> (deleted), I ran into a different, though similar issue, when rotating a layer within a custom `UIView` subclass.

A video of an iPhone Simulator session can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzgwBJFKWw8).

The layer looks like it's rotating on the x/y-axis, at a diagonal, rather than rotating around the z-axis, as desired.

The code that performs the rotation is within a view setter method called `setAngle:` as follows:

```
_imageLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

(where `angle` is in degrees).

The complete Xcode project is available [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18450868/LayerRotate.zip).

The original SO question only shows this behaviour after the device orientation is changed, so it looks like there is more gaps in my understanding than I first thought (coming from an OSX background, and using Layers many times, I expected no such issues).

So my question is: why isn't the layer rotating around the z-axis as desired?

Comment: I am getting somewhere with this, and it relates to how the layer `frame` is being set. If I set the `bounds` and `position` instead, then the layer rotates as normal, but the key to this appears to be getting the width/height of the view, accounting for device orientation.  This is where my understanding is lacking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to answer but you preempted me! Anyway here is what I was *going* to say (it really addresses your last point)

The main reason for unpredictable behaviour is that you are setting the frame property on a transformed object. This you cannot do - Apple warns against it<sup>*</sup>: the frame property will return undefined results after a transform has been applied.

SO you should not do this:

```
 //_imageLayer.frame = layerFrame;
```

but setting `bounds` and `center` properties (`position` in the case of CALayers) continues to work as expected, so instead you can do something like this:

```
   _imageLayer.bounds = (CGRect){0,0,min,min};
   _imageLayer.position = self.center;
```

---

* see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) for the frame property in UIView:

> *Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.*

Comment: Ah OK; I missed that, so this was the root cause of the issue.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this issue is now fixed.  Updated project is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18450868/LayerRotate2.zip).

The issues learned were:

- Don't set the view's frame from within the view controller's `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.  <strike>This could have been the root cause of the issue.</strike>  You don't need any of the calculation performed in the custom `[ViewController _currentRect]` method, as long as the autoresize mask is set to stretch the view to window bounds.
- Don't arrange the layers in `[UIView layoutSubviews]` as that is called when the layer is rotated (!!), which is inefficient.  Instead I used `[UIView setBounds:]` to layout the layers.  `setBounds:` is called after device orientation changes, but for some strange reason it's not called on a newly created view, so I overrode `[UIView didMoveToSuperview]` to call it explicitly (`self.bounds = self.bounds;`).  Curiouser and curiouser.
- I set the layer's `bounds` and `position` rather than setting the layer's `frame` when laying it out, <strike>which I thought was the root cause (things started working after I did this), however I can't see how this makes any difference, and I think this was cured as a side-effect of the mistake mentioned in the first bullet point</strike>.  **UPDATE**: As pointed-out in @He Was's answer; this **is** the root cause.

I won't be marking this answer as correct as I still have an aching feeling that my solution isn't 100% "correct".